# Angular js not behaving properly with html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

This is my small basic angular js code :-

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("MyController",['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.name="Asim";
$scope.f1=function(){   
console.log("i am clicked");
$scope.vr="lol";
}
console.log("angular working");
}]);
```

And this is my index.html code :-

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>

<title> Index </title>
</head>  
<body ng-controller="MyController">    
{{vr}}
{{name}}

<button ng-click="f1()">Click me</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

When I click the button it shows in console "I am clicked" and "angular is working" does print but the {{name}} and {{vr}} doesn't print. Any possible reason??

Plus i am using nodejs and angular code is in "public" folder i.e static folder and my index.html resides in "views" formed when a project with express-generator is created. I got a hint, maybe "name" and "vr" are loaded after the index.html page is rendered, so they don't print and everything else works, ANYWAY TO FIX SUCH THING?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: No error there.

Comment: My angular code resides in "public" folder. And the index.html is in "views" folder. Folder pattern is according to express-generator scene.

Comment: what does it print in places for {{vr}} and even {{name}} should always print, does not depend on click

Comment: It prints nothing. There is only a button "Click Me" on the screen. I tried Opera and Chrome same case.

Comment: delete the cache and try again

Comment: Sometimes you need to use $scope.$$apply to effect the change inside the click function...

Comment: and sometimes you need to include the JS files at the bottom of the <body>

Comment: try using <span ng-bind="name"></span> and your {{vr}} won't render on your screen cause you are assigning it to scope inside the ng-click function

Comment: ng-bind thing is working. Can you please elaborate and answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind`. Only your name will render because the other variable is getting initialised inside the `ng-click`. You can simply use one way binding.

```
<span ng-bind="name"></span>
```

Comment: There might be any css problem on your view. Maybe that is why the data is not appearing in the view port of the screen when you are using vanilla {{name}} inside body. Using span will make sure that your data is tied to a valid html

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be working, I think, am I missing something?

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("MyController",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.name="Asim";
    $scope.f1=function(){
        console.log("i am clicked");
        $scope.vr="lol";
    }
    console.log("angular working");
}]);
</script>

<title> Index </title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
    {{vr}}
    {{name}}
    <button ng-click="f1()">Click me</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, see my app.js and index.html are in different files.

Comment: Then I guess you `app.js` file is not loaded in html tag maybe try `<script src="./public/app.js"></script>` or `<script src="./app.js"></script>`

Comment: I think script is loading thats why I see "angular working" in console.